# On click of the card control display the data into table control

Tags: powerbi

Simple task but not able to figure out the way.

In Power Bi Report , I have 3 different  data tables  contains service data. On report we have  3 cards and a table. all the cards display average availability of the service.
the requirement is, on click of the card, I should display the rest of table data in below table control.

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: or can we hide or unhide the tables on click of cards in power bi.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First save a Bookmark for how you want your table data to appear.

Add a Shape / Rectangle and position it on top of a Card. Set it's Line Color / Weight to 0pts and turn off the Fill.  Turn on it's Action and set the Action / Type = Bookmark and choose your new Bookmark (ref above).

Repeat for each Card.

Comment: For more info on book mark: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NorDWXgCE3E, and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Afcj8mT5_Q

Comment: Does this still work? i have added rectangles to my my cards and configured them as described but when i click (both in power BI desktop & in the service, nothing happens. If i go to the bookmarks panel and click on the bookmark names, my dashboard refreshes as expected.

Comment: Ok, its sort of working now but the problem i have is that the rectangle is being placed behind the card. Just wondering if it can brought to the front

Comment: Easy - select the shape and go to the Visual Tools / Format menu and choose Bring forward / Bring to front.  You can also use the Selection Pane.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of PowerBI Desktop you can add "Bookmark Buttons" and tie their actions to bookmarks.

1. Filter the table and add a bookmark using the "Bookmark Pane" found
   in the View menu.
2. Create a bookmark button and position it where you want it over the Card.
3. Resize the button to fit the icon (unless you want a title for that button).
4. Edit the button's action in the "Visualization Pane" to apply the bookmark you want.

Note in the picture below, the Missing Creative Types bookmark button was selected and the filter was applied to show the 3 rows with the missing data.

[Bookmark illustrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyJ60.png)